# formula to split text in 1 cell without delimiter

Tags: google-sheets

I was wondering is there any formula on spreadsheet to split text without delimiter?

For example :

Column A : Steven JameKing Ring

Expected Output :
Col B : Steven James
Col C : King Ring

I really need your help to solve this formula.
Thanks!

I have no idea which formula that can solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
=regexextract(A1,"(.*[a-z])([A-Z].*)")
```

Or:

```
=split(regexreplace(A1,"([a-z])([A-Z])","$1❄️$2"),"❄️")
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(A1, "([A-Z])", "×$1"), " ×", " "), "×")
```

[image]

[image]